# Query timeout not working for MS SQL server in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to set a query timeout in my spring boot Rest API. I am executing a stored procedure (read only). But the timeout does not work.

I am using MS SQL server as datasource.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://<servername>;instanceName=<instancename>;DatabaseName=<dbname>
```

spring boot version

```
2.4.4
```

Tried below options -

1. Setting @Transactional annotation with timeout

```
@Repository
public class StoredProcImpl  {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional (timeout = 30)
    public String getList() throws Exception {

        StoredProcedureQuery query = this.entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("proc");
        query.setParameter("PAGE_NUMBER", offset);
        query.execute();

}
```

2. setting hint in the query

```
@Repository
public class StoredProcImpl  {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public String getList() throws Exception {

        StoredProcedureQuery query = this.entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("proc");
        query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 30);
        query.setParameter("PAGE_NUMBER", offset);
        query.execute();

}
```

also with

```
query.setHint("org.hibernate.timeout", 30)
```

None of the options work and the query continues to wait even after 30 seconds.

Any help or pointers to set the time out is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the timeout using JPA's javax.persistence.query.timeout property. The value is the timeout period in milliseconds. It's an optional part of the JPA spec, but Hibernate supports it. You can configure it in Spring Boot by adding the following to application.properties:

```
 spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=60000
```

To make the timeout generic, in your JpaConfiguration, when you declare the PlatformTransactionManager Bean, you can set the default timeout of the transactions:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    txManager.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    txManager.setDefaultTimeout(10); //Put 10 seconds timeout
    return txManager;
}
```

PlatformTransactionManager inherits AbstractPlatformTransactionManager which contains that method:

```
  public final void setDefaultTimeout(int defaultTimeout) {
        if (defaultTimeout < TransactionDefinition.TIMEOUT_DEFAULT) {
            throw new InvalidTimeoutException("Invalid default timeout", defaultTimeout);
        }
        this.defaultTimeout = defaultTimeout;
    }
```

Comment: @Sridhar V I am editing my answer please check

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do not have any JpaConfiguration in my code for transaction manager. Could you please elaborate on where exactly to set or use it. I have a NamedStoredProcedureQuery which describes the stored proc to be called along with in and out parameters.  It is being executed in the getList() method as shown in my issue description.

Comment: You can do it yourself by typing in the configuration class or you can add it to the main class

Comment: how should i use the txManager in the query ?

Comment: In your case, you must write configuration class